# Error in startActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I keep getting an error with this source code. Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

```
package com.fttech.da;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class mainMenu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       final Intent intent =    new Intent(this, DorothyTalk.class);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
        Button talk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.talk);

        talk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Every time i click the button i get a Force close error.

Here is the second activity source code.

```
package com.fttech.da;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DorothyTalk extends Activity{

    private TextView text1;
    private EditText edit;
    private Button respond;
    private String name;


    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dorothyDialog);




    }   
}
```

Comment: what's the error from logcat?

Comment: Please add your AndroidManifest.xml and logs from LogCat with stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have something like

```
<activity android:name=".DorothyTalk"></activity>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Wow..Thanks @John Boker. I forgot to add my activity to android manifest!

Comment: But when you call activity explicitly you don't need to add it.

Comment: @damluar I disagree.  from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html : description:
    Declares an activity (an Activity subclass) that implements part of the application's visual user interface. All activities must be represented by <activity> elements in the manifest file. Any that are not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be run.

Comment: I read in the book, I might be wrong, but it's how I remember it. We can check )

Comment: yep is a requirement you have to declare the activity in your manifest.xml